# How to get the original name of a object when sending a list of objects to a function

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following function:

```
return_name <- function(data){
  for(datasets in data)   
    print(deparse(substitute(datasets)))
}

my_data_1 <- data.frame(a = "a", b = "b")
my_data_2 <- data.frame(a = "a", b = "b")
return_name(list(my_data, my_data_2))
```

I'd like to be able for this function to print `my_data_1` followed by `my_data_2` (the name of the object in memory.

Instead it prints the structure of the entire object.

Edit for @Ronak

In my actual code I am iterating over a list of dataframes (not a named list).  I need to be able to `grep` on the name of the current object in the for loop.

It looks something like this:

```
data_list = list(my_data_1, my_data_2)
random_function <- function(data_list){
  for(datasets in data_list)  
    value = ifelse(grepl("my_data_1", return_name(datasets)), 1, 0) 
}
```

The problem is that the return_name function described in your answer will return "datasets" and not the actual, original object name.

Comment: what's wrong with `return(names(data))` being the entirety of `return_name`? Or just using `names` to start with?

Comment: It's not a named list, so that will return `NULL`

Comment: Oh I see. I think what you want is `match.call` to extract the original call to the function, and you can then parse the argument as you'd like. Personally, I don't endorse this as you'll get different functionality if you define the list inside or outside of the function, but to each their own.

Comment: When you pass `data_list` it has no information about `my_data_1` or `my_data_2`. Can you make it a named list? `data_list = list(my_data_1 = my_data_1, my_data_2 = my_data_2)`

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I was hoping there was a way to recover the original name somehow.  If a named list is necessary, I can just make it a named list.  The original codebase uses un-named lists, so I was trying to work within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a hack :

```
return_name <- function(data){
   strsplit(gsub('list|[()]', '', deparse(substitute(data))), ',\\s*')[[1]]
}

return_name(list(my_data, my_data_2))
#[1] "my_data"   "my_data_2"
return_name(my_data_1)
#[1] "my_data_1"
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This works in the context you provided, but in my actual code, I will need to replace the `print(deparse(substitute(datasets)))` line because it will be inside a for loop that is iterating over all the data.frames in a list.  

If I do something like: 

```return_name_2 <- function(data){
  for(datasets in data)   
    print(return_name(datasets)
}```

I'll get `datasets` returned.  Any thoughts?